# How to get and store registration details from user for later login in XAML Windows store apps

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, store

Hello am a newbie with windows store app so am devoloping an app that requires a user to register before he can login so am trying to figure out how to get user inputs on registration form mayb store it a database or sometging so that he can login with the exact same registered details!
Xaml windows store app

Answer (score 0):

To get the users' registration details, you could retrieve the credentials from the Credential Locker after you have a reference to the `PasswordVault` object.

You can implement `PasswordVault.RetrieveAll()` method to retrieve all the user has supplied for your app.

You might refer to the sample [**Retrieving user credentials**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker#retrieving-user-credentials):

***"where we have stored the resource name globally in an app and we log the user on automatically if we find a credential for them. If we find multiple credentials for the same user, we ask the user to select a default credential to use when logging on".***

To store these details, you need to use `PasswordVault.Add()` method to pass the username and password to a `PasswordCredential` object:

```
var vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();
vault.Add(new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(
    "My App", username, password));
```

For more details, please see **[Windows.Security.Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Credentials)**.

If you want to store them into a database, you can use SQLite to save and get the data. To learn how to use SQLite on the Universal Windows Platform , please refer to **[this blog](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx)** written by @Diederik Krols.